# Is possible to see multiple filters in the django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, filtering, customization

I need to be able to filter for 2 fields at the same time. For example, Filter by Country and by Gender. But is possible to see both filters at the top/side at the same time?

P.D: I think I explain this poorly. I know is possible in a dropdown-like menu to see both filters. But I want to know if is possible to see both horizontally like this:

Filter By: - Status - | - City -

Comment: did you mean ordering? :) https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2110/

Comment: No, I mean filtering

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter also you can override `SimpleListFilter` for your needs

Answer (score 0):

The following would bring up the two possibilities:

```html
list_filter=('Country','Gender',)
```